# Tweet from my website without prompting any window and requiring any authentication - Is it possible?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I'm developing a personal project in which many users join a certain project and are able to view the information on it. Besides that, I'd like to be able that a user could tweet to the other users, warning he is online.

E.g.: user1, user2 and user3 share a project. If user1 is online, but user2 and user3 aren't, user1 would then click a button that would send a tweet (e.g., "@user2twitteraccount User1 is online!") to user2 and user3. The tweet sender would be an account of the website, not user1's Twitter account.

Is that possible to be done? 'Cause, from what I've seen so far, there are two options that are mainly used: 
1) The "share button" option (Requires authentication): there is a share button, which sends a tweet on the user's timeline. It prompts a screen so the user can write whatever he want to tweet.
2) The "authorization-required" option (Requires authentication and application authorization): an application tweets on behalf of the user on his timeline.

Besides the things that I have stated, the main thing that bothers me about these options is that they tweet on behalf of the user on his account. As I am looking for a solution on which, instead of using the user's Twitter, the user would tweet throughout my site's Twitter, they doesn't work for me.

Am I missing to see something quite obvious in here, or what I want to achieve isn't quite usual? Do you know any ways that I could achieve this solution? Thanks.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to make it so these tweets are sent from the user's Twitter account, or from one that you control?

Comment: If the former, by the way, think about *why* that shouldn't be possible without authentication/authorization: it would allow you to arbitrarily send tweets with the user's account from your site without requiring their input; certainly not something the user (or Twitter) would want you to be able to do.

Comment: Yes, I understand that... And, exactly for not wanting any authentication beside my website's, I'm going for this approach: send tweets from the account I control, through an action triggered by the user (A click of a button, for example).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your best bet would be to use the Twitter [web intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)
You could then tweet to @user2 and @user3 from the account of @user1 adding a via @appname to the tweet text.
NOTE: @appname should be the twitter account of your app.
If this is unsatisfactory, then you should do what [sarnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377270/sarnold) says as that would be the best option
(Only suggested the intents thing because you want to avoid requesting authorization)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, if the project has 10 users, would be tiresome for the user to confirm 10 tweets. That's why I wanna make the things with less user interaction as possible. Thanks for your idea, thought.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

[Register your application](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) and then [`POST` tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) as you want to send new messages.

Comment: I'll probably will use this approach. I already registered my application, and already got the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. What is left now is just POST to "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json" with the data I want to POST? Simple as that?

Comment: Oh, I also got an access token and an access token secret from my Twitter account... Just don't know where to go from here...

Comment: The examples shown in your link use username/password authentication. Isn't this kind of authentication unavailable, because they are enforcing the OAuth now?

Comment: Oh bother, I forgot about that transition. :(

Comment: I will already mark your solution as the ideal one, but would you have by any chance a step-by-step tutorial or something like that for this?

Comment: Don't jump to accepting prematurely; I don't have such a tutorial handy, but someone else might put in the effort to write a better answer if they believe the question hasn't yet had a definitive answer. I suggest waiting a while. :)

Comment: Ok, then... I'll wait some more. =)